# MapView is loading no location

Tags: android, android-mapview

I am trying to load Google map but it is not loading in the app.
I followed many tutorials and threads here but no help.what is the problem.
Manifest:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.robotracker"
      android:versionCode="1"
       android:versionName="1.0" >


        <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
        <permission
         android:name="com.robotracker.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECIEVE"
         android:protectionLevel="signature"
         />
        <usespermissionandroid:name="com.robotracker.googlemapsv2.permission.MPAS_RECIEVE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
        <usespermission
         android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
        <uses-permission 
          android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission 
         android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-feature 
         android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
        <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AKzaSyA88_rd2tZaAB8HS3_y3czsaRKOlb45XZY"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

XML:

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context="com.robotracker.MainActivity">
```

I am using the api key I got from my account.I generated sha1 fingerprints with keytools.

```
   <com.google.android.maps.MapView
   android:id="@+id/mapview1"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:enabled="true"
   android:clickable="true"
   android:apiKey="AKzaSyA88_rd2tZaAB8HS3_y3czsaRKOlb45XZY" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where is the rest of the xml? The map for instance

Comment: Is your package name allowed access using that API key in the developer console?

Comment: I updated it.see above.I followed many tutorials to load the map but every time I got failed

Comment: yes.com.robotracker? yes i put it after the sha1 finger print;

Comment: Hello Anybody help me. :(